# style of Django template is ignored when set as ReactJS dangerouslySetInnerHTML value

Tags: django, reactjs

My ultimate target is to come up with `Print` functionality. For some reason, HTML just HAS TO BE generated on the backend. So I have the following code:

```
<div
     ref={el => (this.componentRef = el)}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.htmlToPrint}}>
</div>
```

For sake of simplicity, let's assume that the `htmlToPrint` is just

```
<div style='background: red'></div>
```

Now, the problem is that the css encompassed in `style` is ignored. And the strangest think is that when run locally, everything is fine. But after being deployed, the red effect is gone away. I have read that `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` can have issues with `style`, but why do I experience the issue only on the remote server? Does it have to do something with nginx ?

Comment: What do you mean by "inline css is ignored"? Do you mean that it ends up in the browser inspector, but the browser doesn't interpret it? Or you mean that CSS disappears when you use your production bundle?

Comment: I just mean the css in `style` tag

Comment: I understand that you mean the `style` attribute. I want to clarify what do you mean by "ignored". What is the difference between generated HTML in the local environment and in the production? Does `style` tag get stripped somehow? What browser inspector is showing?

Comment: The html per se is all right. But the actual graphical effect is missing (in this example, div background color is not red)

Comment: This is super-weird, the browser should apply inline CSS. Can you show a screenshot of a browser inspector with the simplest possible failing case?

Comment: Maybe there's something trying to sanitize HTML in the response data and turns it into escaped HTML entities. In this case it might not work, check https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5616